# Use of Hint with jdbc call -Spring jdbc batch

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have two questions related to Spring jdbc batch insert :
if anybody can help me on this

Question 1:
Scenario :
The insert statement is : `INSERT into EMPLOYEE_TABLE VALUES(....);`

```
query = "INSERT into EMPLOYEE_TABLE VALUES(....)";
dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
```

Can I have hint `/*+APPEND_VALUES*/` to the insert statement ?I mean Is there any disadvantage of having hint in jdbc call ?

Question 2 :
What could be maximum batch size ojdbc6.jar can have ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**: The main disadvantage I can think of is that you are relying in a Oracle-only feature. In this particular case it is not too bad as that hint should not change query semantics.

**Question 2**: I don't know about theoretical maximum batch sizes, and anyway I recommend selecting a "good" generic initial value (I tend to choose 75, anything between 50 and 100 willd do), and refine this value by profiling your particular use case. Very often your initial value will be good enough as is.

Comment: What is meant by Oracle only feature ? If I am sticking to oracle OLTP database wouldn't be good ? Do you have any other alternative ?

Comment: @Md Faraz Some applications are meant to be cross-platform: adding platform specific features is undesirable in these cases; if you know the application will not ever run on anything other than Oracle, I guess it is ok to use Oracle specific features